# Redux: Where to place "dumb" handlers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have a component with a click handler that doesn't need to modify the Redux store. i.e. it might, depending on the props of the component, initiate a download of a file.

i.e. you have an web interface for a list of videos that are processing on the server. Click on a video item checks the props to see if the video has finished processing. If it has, it'll start downloading the video, other it'll pop up an alert explaining that the video is still processing.

Usually, handlers tend to be defined in `mapDispatchToProps`. However, in this case, I don't actually need to touch the state, so defining the handler in there doesn't feel correct.

Would the correct place for such a handler be in the 'dumb' component rather than the 'smart' container?

Answer (score 2):

I would still have this in the container and pass the function down as a prop -- just not in `mapDispatchToProps`.

e.g:

```js
// SmartComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DumbComponent from '/path/to/DumbComponent'

export class SmartComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleOnClick(params) {
    // do whatever you need to do here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DumbComponent handleOnClick={this.handleOnClick} />
    );
  }
};

export default SmartComponent;
```

```js
// DumbComponent.js

import React from 'react'
import Button from '/path/to/button'

export const DumbComponent = (props) = {
  const { handleOnClick } = props;
  return (
    <Button onClick={handleOnClick} />
  );
}

export default DumbComponent;
```

I should probably also add that I usually structure it so that I have another level above this which is connected to the store - something like `ContainerComponent` for example - which is usually the view for the route. This is why I have not connected this `SmartComponent` to the store. You could do that though.